# Communicate between content script and options page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, request

I have seen many questions already and all are about background page to content script.

### Summary

My extension has an options page, and a content script. The content script handles the storage functionality (`chrome.storage` manipulation). 
Whenever, a user changes a setting in the options page, I want to send a message to the content script to store the new data.

### My code:

**options.js**

```
var data = "abcd"; // let data

chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, "storeData:" + data, function(response){
        console.log(response); // gives undefined :(
    });
 });
```

**content script js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    // not working
});
```

### My question:

1. Why isn't the approach not working?
2. Is there any other (better) approach for this procedure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1) Why isn't the approach not working?

You are trying to message yourself: an options page on which you're doing something is returned by `chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, ...);`

> 2) Is there any other (better) approach for this procedure.

It depends on which page you're trying to message. You could just message *all* pages: query with an empty filter and iterate over the result.

You could keep track of the last active tab with your content script, but it sounds overcomplicated.

Or, you could just use the fact that changes to `chrome.storage` generate `onChanged` events in *all* extension contexts. If you modify options saved in `chrome.storage`, your content scripts can listen to `onChanged` events and reprocess their data as needed, and this way you just skip messaging completely.

Answer (score 0):

Accurate matching mode:

`{ currentWindow: true, url: 'http://127.0.0.1/*' }`

**options page**

```js
chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, url: 'http://127.0.0.1/*' }, tabs => {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, 'popup-tabs send a message');
});
```

**content script**

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  console.log('request: ', request);
});
```